# Change button background color dynamically like progress bar

Tags: swift, button, uibutton

I am trying to implement buttons with changeable background colors in Swift. But I do not want to change color of whole button. I want it to change like progress bar. For example, there will be a specific time value, and background color of button should change from right to left with animation in that time.
I saw apps like that. Can anyone give a clue for how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Don't be constrained by the idea that a button is only a `UIButton`. A button can be a view with a gesture recogniser, or a view with a transparent button over the top of it. It could be a button with a background image that you keep updating. There are many options for how to construct what you describe. It depends exactly what effect you want as to how it should be done. Buttons showing progress would often be disabled until progress is complete so you could easily use a progress indication view which is replaced by a 'real' button when progress is complete.

Comment: Can you elaborate it with an example please?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you.

```
 func changeButtonColors(){
    //let myBtn

    let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: "changeColor", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    timer.fire()

 }

 //cloros to iterate over each time
 let colorChoice = [UIColor.blackColor(), UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.redColor()]  
  var counter = 0   //tracking variable

 //this gets called when by the timer
 //currently it is supposed to go on forever. 
 func changeColor(){
        //suppose i have the button outlet named myBtn

        UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, animations: { () -> Void in
            myBtn.backgroundColor = colorChoice[counter]

            if counter < colorChoice.count{
                counter++
            }else{
                counter = 0
                //or disable the alert
                //timer.invalidate()
            }
        })
    }
```

Here myBtn is a outlet to the View Controller. We use Timer to trigger the function call at a specific time in our case every 2 second. This can be derived by other app logic.

The called function then iterates over a array of UIColor and applies one to the background of the button or view. The workflow is this. Change things where you require.

Comment: It will change the whole background color. I asked for a color change that starts from right and continue to the left like progress bar.